# Types of Jhana!

Tags: theravada

What type of Jhana (Vimuttimagga or Visuddhimagga) would you recommend?
Is it possible for a Laity to attain all the four levels of Visuddhimagga Jhana?

Metta.

Charles.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Charles. Ven. Yuttadhammo doesn't answer question on this site; but other users may.

Comment: what is the difference between Vimuttimagga or Visuddhimagga jhāna?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for lay people as well. It requires freedom of remorse which means firm [virtue](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sila/index_en.html) by heart AND (especially since still much possessing) [liberation of stingyness](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.254.than_en.html).

Usually lay people would use this six (ten) *kammaṭṭhānas* to develop refined concentration:

**[Recollections, ten (anussati).](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/index-subject_en.html#recollections)**

- Recollection of the Buddha (buddhanussati): SN 11.3, AN 3.70, AN 11.12, AN 11.13, Thag 6.2
- Recollection of the Dhamma (dhammanussati): SN 11.3, AN 3.70, AN 11.12, AN 11.13, Thag 6.2
  As a governing principle: AN 3.40
- Recollection of the Sangha (sanghanussati): SN 11.3, AN 3.70, AN 11.12, AN 11.13, Thag 6.2
- Recollection of one's own virtues (silanussati): AN 3.70, AN 11.12, AN 11.13
- Recollection of one's own generosity (caganussati): AN 11.12, AN 11.13
- Recollection of the devas (devatanussati): AN 3.70, AN 11.12, AN 11.13
- [Mindfulness of death (maranassati) (see also Satipatthana).
- Mindfulness of the body (kayagatasati) (see also Satipatthana).
- Mindfulness of breathing (anapanasati) (see also Satipatthana).]
- Recollection of peace (upasamanussati): Iti 90
  "[A Meditator's Tools: A Study Guide on the Ten Recollections](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/recollections_en.html)"

As the word "recollection" already indicates, there have to be something to recollect.

Once a lay person can with ease recollect on the six he/she might have already entered the path of Dhamma.

Then it should be possible to also reach higher Jhanas by will, using the certain "mindfulness objects" (on the body parts till 1. Jhana, or Ānāpānassati for all others) since the other recollection are said lead "only" to Upacārasamādhi (proper concentration). If conditions allow serious practicing the Brahmaviharas, they are also open for a good use to reach certain Jhanas.

So everybodies requirements are to listen to the good Dhamma, find firm faith and seek for refuge in the Buddha, the Dhamma and the Sangha of his disciples (real devotion and refuge), taking on the precepts by heart (right resolve, real metta) and real generosity. Once those things are firm, there should be less obstacles for the reaching of Jhanas.

All possible attainments are possible for householders as well, of course attainments have at least, if not before effects on ways of livelihood possible for one having reached certain state of clarification. Certain circumstances make possible attainments and practice more difficult but it's like always at least an individual, kammic, matter: if, what and how in detail and ways to meet the Noble Eightfold Path.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*